# Suppose that A is an n-element set, and that B is a k-element subset of A. What is the number of subsets of A whose intersection with B has 1 element?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble figuring out this problem, and I am not really sure where to start. I know I should divide into three sections:

1. subset has all of the elements of $B$
2. subset has none of the elements of $B$
3. subset has one of the elements of $B$.

After this I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Out the $k$ elements in $B$, we have to pick 1.
For the $n-k$ elements that are in $A \backslash B$, we have to decide if they are in the subset.

Comment: I still don't understand completely, why is it _n-k_ elements? How do we decide if they are in the subset? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MINTCHIP37 What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried by determining that 2^n is the total subsets. So, if 2^n has _k_ - elements, all of B, then that would be .. ah I am not sure. I am really stuck. If _n-k_ is the numbers of elements in subset B, then ... I am not sure, sorry. I feel really lost.

Comment: @MINTCHIP37 Consider small cases. Suppose $ A = \{1, 2, 3, 4 \} $ and $B = \{1, 2 \}$, then what are all of the sets that satisfy your condition?

Comment: Then, the subsets {1}, {2}, {2,3,4}, and {1,3,4} satisfy the condition.

Comment: What about $ \{ 1, 3 \}$? Are you missing any others?

Comment: Oh yes, and {2,3} and {2,4}

Comment: So, one of $\{ 1, 2 \}$ must be in the set. What can we say about the elements $3, 4$?

Comment: Elements 3 and 4 are sometimes in the set? But not always

Comment: Right, those elements may or may not be in the subset. So, can you come up with an argument for why there are $ 2 \times 2^2$ such subsets?

Comment: Is it because 3 and 4 can be alone or together, so 2^2? And then 1 and 2 have to be alone so it is multiplied by 2? Does that make sense? I am not sure

Comment: Now apply that logic to $ A = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \}, B = \{1, 2, 3 \}$. If you're successful with that, try your original problem.

Comment: Ok, I think it is starting to make sense to me. Would it be 3 X 2^3 for the number of subsets the condition applies to?

Comment: Close, but not quite.  Can you explain why $ 2^3$?

Comment: I thought 2^3 because this time there are 2 elements (4 and 5) that are not in subset B, but more subsets they can be apart of with 2 elements or 3 elements. Therefore it seemed like there was another set of 2 being added to the possibilities if that makes sense. I am thinking now, maybe it is 3 X 2^2 but I don't know exactly why.

Comment: How many subsets of $ \{ 4, 5 \}$ are there? Is it $2^2 $ or $2^3$? Why / How can we tell?

Comment: There are 2^2 subsets of {4,5} because they are {none}, {4}, {5}, and {4,5}